# store users geolocation in 30 second intervals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, google-maps

I'm trying to figure out how I can refactor my code so that I can send a user's geolocation to my `MySQL` database in 30 second intervals.

This code below store's a users geolocation in the table **only** when the application is loaded or if the application is refreshed but It does not continuously store the geolocation as the person travels. I am looking to send the users geolocation to the server periodically in 30 second bursts.

I am aware of `jquery` setInterval and have tried to nest it in several places without success as `javascript` is rusty.

Any steering would be greatly appreciated.

> My Table Schema

[image]

> heatmap.php

```html
<?php require_once("../resources/config.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FOX COUNT</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/heatmapstyle.css">
  
  <style>
    /*  NOTE: GOOGLE MAPS NEEDS HTTPS TO WORK. IT WILL NOT WORK WITH HTTP AKA UNSECURE ORIGIN */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map">
    <!--Google map will be embedded here-->
  </div>
  <script>
    var map, currentPositionMarker, map;
    function initializeMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 16,

      });
    }

    function locError(error) {

      // tell the user if the current position could not be located
      alert("The current position could not be found!");
    }
    
    // current position of the user

    function setCurrentPosition(pos) {

      currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        label: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          text: 'CD',
        },

        map: map,

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
          pos.coords.latitude,
          pos.coords.longitude,

        ),
        title: "Current Position"

      });
      var a = pos.coords.latitude;
      var b = pos.coords.longitude;
      console.log(a, b);


      // This ajax command stores the lat and lang into the db ONLY when the app loads from fresh or if the app refreshes. It DOES NOT continously store the users geolocation when ever the user marker changes geolocation.  !!!

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "personlocator.php",
        data: {
          a: a,
          b: b
        }
      })
      
      map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
        pos.coords.latitude,
        pos.coords.longitude
      ));
    } // end of function ///////////////////////////

    function watchCurrentPosition(pos) {
      var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        function(position) {
          setMarkerPosition(
            currentPositionMarker,
            position
          );
        });
    }

    function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
      marker.setPosition(
        new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude,
          position.coords.longitude)
      );


    }
    
    function initLocationProcedure() {

      initializeMap();
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCurrentPosition, watchCurrentPosition, locError);
      } else {
        // tell the user if a browser doesn't support this amazing API
        alert("Your browser does not support the Geolocation API!");
      }
    }
  </script>
  
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_IS_NESTED_HERE&libraries=visualization&callback=initLocationProcedure">
  </script>

  <!--javascript and jquery CDN's directly beneath here-->
  
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

> personlocator.php

```
if (isset($_GET['a'], $_GET['b'])) { 
  $latitude   = escape_string($_GET['a']); 
  $longitude  = escape_string($_GET['b']); 
  $updateQuery = $mysqli->query("UPDATE users  
                   SET user_latitude='$latitude'
                     , user_longitude='$longitude' 
                  WHERE id= '{$id}' ");

  mysqli_query($connection,$updateQuery); 
  confirm($updateQuery);
  redirect("personlocator.php");
}
```

Comment: `var timer = setInterval('setCurrentPosition', 30000, pos);`

Comment: Can you update my code please to where this would be nested.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Thank you, I will run this and revert back shortly

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest it like this:

```
function initLocationProcedure() {
  initializeMap();

  if (navigator.geolocation) {

    // Timer with setInterval
    var timer = setInterval( function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setCurrentPosition, locError);
    }, 30000);

  } else {
    // tell the user if a browser doesn't support this amazing API
    alert("Your browser does not support the Geolocation API!");
  }
}
```

Comment: where am I nesting the jquery url and data GET in here or do I not need to??

Comment: no need, this edit will schedule the execution of your code every 30 seconds

Comment: grafi sorry to keep rattling on mate, one of the things that Im confused about with this API, surely their needs to be an initial send that that does and INSERT statement before the UPDATE and SET as you can't UPDATE and SET first

Comment: I guess so, this routine seems to take for granted that a `user` record with the right `ID` is already present in DB.

Comment: where would you do the initial insert and how

Comment: Depending on your application deployment, users might register themselves on the platform or they get inserted in db by some operator via an administration tool. In those 2 cases, user records in db are inserted for the first time way before handling their geoposition.